# Is it possible to download file straight to file/blob sotrage using app functions?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

Working on some pipeline. Is there a way to download file straight to blob/file service instead of locally? I know how to upload files using `ContainerClient` but first I need to download them locally. The thing is that the download file will exceed 700mb and getting it locally first will be long and inefficient.

My goal is to automate the process as much as possible and this will include:

- Download file (csv) straight to blob/file using app functions
- Load this csv to temp sql table and compare with global table (to add new rows)
- Delete temp table
- Perfrom some sql queries to check results

More/less I know how to perform these steps except downloading the file. Appreciate any hints :)

Comment: Where is the source file located?

Comment: @GauravMantri Im not sure If i can link the external sources. It is hosting -  zippyshare.com link

Comment: What I meant to ask is if the file is publicly accessible? In other words, if I directly type in the file's URL in a browser it will be downloaded. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: @GauravMantri it is publicly accesible. You just click the link and download process starts in browser

Answer (score 0):

If the file you wish to save directly in blob storage is publicly accessible, then you can make use of `async blob copy` to copy it directly in Azure Blob Storage without going through the download and upload process.

The method you would want to call is [`start_copy_from_url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#start-copy-from-url-source-url--metadata-none--incremental-copy-false----kwargs-) which is available in [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python).

Please note that this operation is asynchronous i.e. a request is sent to Azure Storage to copy a blob from URL when call to the method above completes successfully.

Your code must wait for the copy operation to complete successfully before you can read the contents of that blob.

You can check the status of the copy operation by repeatedly calling [`get_blob_properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#get-blob-properties---kwargs-) and checking the copy operation status or you can call `status()` on the returned polling object to check the status of the copy operation, or `wait()` to block until the operation is complete. The final blob will be committed when the copy completes.